# Two items (dates) the same in logger but not fulfilling "if" condition. Javascript / Google Scripts

Tags: javascript, date

I'm having trouble meeting an if condition and I've run out of ideas. I've been using the logger to check if the two variables are the same, and they appear identical in the logger and the code runs fine. Here is my code:

```
//Get two ranges from Google sheets and turn into values, (inputValues and datesValues)
...
for (var i = 0; i < inputValues.length; i++) {
  if ((inputValues[i][2].length > 0) && (inputValues[i][29].length > 0)) {
    //This creates an event in Google Calendar. Works fine.
    var eventNum = i;
    Logger.log(datesValues[3][4]); // this is to test - results below
    Logger.log(inputValues[eventNum][30]);
      for (var k = 0; k < datesValues.length; k++) {
        if (datesValues[k][4] == inputValues[eventNum][30]){
          Logger.log("yes");
          //Things in this loop that I want to do but can't.
            }
          }
       }
     }
```

Here is what the Logger returns:

[16-12-12 09:11:50:951 PST] Thu Dec 15 20:00:00 GMT+01:00 2016

[16-12-12 09:11:50:952 PST] Thu Dec 15 20:00:00 GMT+01:00 2016

I'm basically not able to trip the second "`if`" clause, even though there is an "`i`" such that `datesValues[3][4] == inputValues[eventNum][30]`. Those logs look identical to me! The for loop before the if loop is also working correctly, `datesValues.length = 50`.

Is there something weird in javascript about dates and logical operators that I don't know about?

Thanks!

Comment: use another variable in second `for` loop instead of `i`

Comment: You log `datesValues[3][4]`, but test against `datesValues[i][4]`. Are you sure that the first `if ` statement evaluates to true when `i = 3`?

Comment: @JordanBurnett that's probably a tag added by the logger library.

Comment: what about the milliseconds?

Comment: @azad Currently have that in my code - sorry, updated the post here. Issue remains.

Comment: @JordanBurnett That is a logger tag, as Dan pointed out.

Comment: @canton7 Yup, when I manually change the code to 'datesValues[3][4]' I still can't trip the 'if'

Comment: What actually are those things you're comparing?  Just strings of the date/time, or some sort of object, where two of them are _different objects_ but might have _the same string representation_ when logged?

Comment: I had the same thought as @JamesThorpe is asking, what are the types of objects you are storing in the `dateValues` arrays?

Comment: its clear those two logs are not equal

Comment: The first one logged has 951 milliseconds, the second has 952 milliseconds so they aren't equal. You should consider your meaning of equal for your case. When comparing dates and times it is common to consider them equal in cases where you don't care for the millisecond precision. You would need to either parse the string to strip milliseconds or convert to actual date objects and then set milliseconds to 0 before comparison.

Comment: @mcgraphix That was covered in the earlier comments - the stuff between brackets is the logging code running. The fact that the OP is using it to log a date/time string further confuses the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried comparing the strings instead of whatever object those variables represent:

```
if (datesValues[k][4].toString() == inputValues[eventNum][30].toString()){
...
}
```

When you compare date objects, they are not the same object even if they represent the same date. For example this will return false:

```
console.log(new Date(2017, 1, 1) == new Date(2017, 1, 1)); // returns false
```

When comparing dates, you can compare the string representation as above or the value returned from getTime() which would be my preferred approach.

```
console.log(new Date(2017, 1, 1).getTime() == new Date(2017, 1, 1).getTime()); //returns true
```

Comment: It worked! Thank you. I guess there was something strange about the date objects, and changing them to strings caused the If clause to immediately return 'true'. Thanks!